# Does a homological Segal condition make sense?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

A $\Gamma$-space is a pointed functor from pointed finite sets to pointed spaces. Segal said that a $\Gamma$-space $F$ is *special* if the natural map $F(X\vee Y)\to F(X)\times F(Y)$ is a weak homotopy equivalence for all $X, Y$. Let us say that $F$ is *homologically special* if this map is an integral homology isomorphism for all $X, Y$.

**Question 1**: Did anyone consider such a homological version of Segal's condition?

**Question 2**: Does there exists a $\Gamma$-space that is homologically special, but not special?

**Question 3**: (assuming that the answer to the previous question is yes) Suppose $F$ is homologically special, and $X$ is path connected. Does it follow that the natural map $F(X)\to \Omega F(S^1\wedge X)$ is a weak homotopy equivalence? Here we extended $F$ from pointed sets to pointed spaces in the usual way.

Comment: I don't understand your question 3. Wasn't $F$ a functor out of finite pointed sets? Are you taking some kind of natural extension to simplicial sets (e.g. taking it levelwise and then geometrically realize)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Equivalently, homotopy left Kan extend $F$ from pointed sets to spaces.

Comment: A silly example of a $\Gamma$-space that is homologically special but not special is given by $X \mapsto X \wedge P$ where $P$ is a nontrivial acyclic space.

Comment: Good example. I guess it takes every connected space to a contractible space, so it does not falsify question 3.